# How to destroy the OpenGL context clearly

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, opengl-es-3.0

I am developing the android app with NDK and using OpenGL. But I have a problem.
Normally, The OpenGL context is created and destroyed many times during the app running.
after a while, OpenGL is giving that error message.

> W/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_ldd_control:553>: ioctl fd 81 code 0xc0080913 (IOCTL_KGSL_DRAWCTXT_CREATE) failed: errno 28 No space left on device

I know that means I couldn't destroy the OpenGL context but it seems everything ok for destroying the OpenGL context. Here is an example of destroying. What can I do to clear the OpenGL context? Or, May it be an Operating System error?

`eglMakeCurrent(this->m_egl_display,EGL_NO_SURFACE,EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL_NO_CONTEXT);`

`eglDestroyContext(this->m_egl_display, this->m_egl_context);`

`eglDestroySurface(this->m_egl_display, this->m_eglSurfacePbuffer);`

`eglTerminate(this->m_egl_display);`

I searched many different websites and saw the following

> https://lwn.net/Articles/394665/

> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36982885

> [https://www.ics.uci.edu/~ardalan/papers/Hung_MobiCom22.pdf](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Eardalan/papers/Hung_MobiCom22.pdf)

I want to learn how to destroy the OpenGL context clearly. But all implementations look like same. Also, I wonder if it is an operating system bug.

Comment: Are you clean up all other stuff before destroying opengl context? Buffers, textures, shader programs?

Comment: Actually, yes I clean up everything.